# how to make my pg query faster

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Im new to pg, and have a table like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_article (
    uid         TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
    tags        JSONB
)
CREATE INDEX idxgin ON tbl_article USING gin (tags);
```

`uid` is something like MongoDB's ObjectID generated in my program.

And this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_article
WHERE tags @> '{"Category":0}'::jsonb
ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 10000
```

Here is explain:

```
Limit  (cost=971.77..971.77 rows=1 width=1047) (actual time=121.811..121.811 rows=0 loops=1)
    ->  Sort  (cost=971.46..971.77 rows=125 width=1047) (actual time=110.653..121.371 rows=8215 loops=1)
    Sort Key: uid
    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8736kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_article  (cost=496.97..967.11 rows=125 width=1047) (actual time=5.292..14.504 rows=8215 loops=1)
          Recheck Cond: (tags @> '{"Category": 0}'::jsonb)
          Heap Blocks: exact=3521
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idxgin  (cost=0.00..496.93 rows=125 width=0) (actual time=4.817..4.817 rows=8216 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (tags @> '{"Category": 0}'::jsonb)
Planning time: 0.105 ms
Execution time: 123.016 ms
```

Seems sorting is so slow. So how to make this faster

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: What is your current setting for work_mem? And did you try a different setting? show work_mem; set work_mem to '100MB';

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thanks for your help, But still take more than 100ms after setting work_mem to '100MB'. I noticed sort method changed to `top-N heapsort Memory: 2104kB` or sometimes `quicksort Memory`.  If I remove the `WHERE` clause, it just take 0.3ms and no `sort`. So I'm wondering why need a `sort` when I add the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @FrankHeikens And I tried different work_mem values like '50MB', '200MB', still the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you still see an external merge Disk when you have lots of memory available? That would be weird. Check, check and double check, something is wrong. Change work_mem, check work_mem, explain your query and check work_mem again. Just to be sure.

Comment: And please show us the new results from explain analyze. OFFSET 10000 is also a bit slow, it has to read and ignore 10000 records before it gets to the ones you're looking for. A cursor might be a better solution, depending on your situation. See also http://explain.depesz.com/s/FYgL

Comment: @FrankHeikens , EXPLAIN analyze here: http://explain.depesz.com/s/E51C , this is `OFFSET 1000`: http://explain.depesz.com/s/P5m